# How to remove bg color of ul

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to remove background color `ul` list but not getting removed.

This is my code

```
<div style="margin-left: 15px; margin-top: 20px;" class="col-md-8 card card-body bg-light">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div id="mydiv2">                             
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div style="border: none;margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 25px;">          
        <ul style="background-color: transparent;" class="list-group .list-group-flush borderless">

          <li style="border: transparent; height: 47px;" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            Item 1
            <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">14</span>
          </li>
          <li style="border: none;  height: 47px;" class="list-group-item borderless ">Item 2</li>
          <li style="border: none;  height: 47px;" class="list-group-item borderless">Item 3</li>            
        </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
</div>
    
<style>
.ul {
background-color:transparent;
}
</style>
```

This is my output

[image]

Comment: is it the `ul` background colour or the box that hold's all the `ul`'s ? Are you using a 3rd person library ? Show more of your css code if you can

Comment: @ZombieChowder -Left side first div with `col-md-8` and another one is `ul`.

Comment: @ZombieChowder - There is no CSS at all and no external libs, using bootstrap4

Answer (score 1):

`ul` is the tag name not class.

you can either
select them with their class names: `.list-group{}`
or just `ul{}`.

also remove the "." from in html class names *`class=".list-group-flush"`.*

If its still not applying try making the css selector more specific so it can override bootstrap. or add `!important` (not recomended)

```
<style>
    ul.list-group{
      background-color: transparent;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: try `ul{ background-color: transparent!important; }`

Comment: This is also not wokring. I have another ul that turned to while same above

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle of your code? https://jsfiddle.net/